# Why is a vector variable with multiple variable types considered a character variable when using the class() function?

Tags: r

```
## a.
## b.
x <- 4
y <- TRUE
z <- "Mort"
## c.
k <- c(x,z)
i <- c(x,y,z)
## d.
class(k)
class(i)
```

The above code comes out with the class of k and i to be a character. Why is it a character when only "Mort" is a character and the others are logical and numerical?

Comment: Vectors in R can only be one type. They will be coerced to a type can can accommodate all the elements.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking along those lines, but I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#vector-basics